# Why does a doubly-reversed iterator act as if it was never reversed?

Tags: rust

I have an input vector which contains numbers. In an output vector, I need to get a sequence of partial products but in right-to-left order. The last element of the output must be equal to the last one in the input; the second-to-last element of the output must be a product of the last and second-to-last elements of input; and so on. For example, if the input vector is

```
let input = vec![2, 3, 4];
```

then I need the output to be `[24, 12, 4]`.

My implementation takes an iterator over the input, reverses it, `map`s, reverses again and `collect`s:

```
fn main() {
    let input = vec![2, 3, 4];
    let mut prod = 1;
    let p: Vec<usize> = input
        .iter()
        .rev()
        .map(|v| {
            prod *= v;
            prod
        }).rev()
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", p);
}
```

[The result is `[2, 6, 24]`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b2312eaa6356fa1eb24d7715a06ad9c6&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015), the same as if I delete both `rev()`s. The two `rev()`s do not solve the problem, they just "annihilate" each other.

Is this task solvable in "chain of calls" style, without using `for`?

Comment: It looks to me like you want a `scan`, not a `map`. And having the `map` operation alter external state is some sort of obfustated `for`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This behavior is actually [explicitly described in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Map.html):

> ## Notes about side effects
>
> The [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) iterator implements [`DoubleEndedIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html), meaning that
>   you can also [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) backwards:
>
> […]
>
> But if your closure has state, iterating backwards may act in a way you do
>   not expect. […]

[A way to solve this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=936faf2d6c03bf83dfaf23a7b8bf26b7&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) would be by adding an intermediary [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) to be sure that the second `rev` does not apply on the `Map`:

```
fn main() {
    let input = vec![2, 3, 4];
    let mut prod = 1;
    let p: Vec<usize> = input
        .iter()
        .map(|v| {
            prod *= v;
            prod
        }).rev()
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .into_iter()
        .rev()
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", p);
}
```

But that requires an extra allocation. [Another way](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=73cd47c46871d0c3472ae77e6e198f94&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) would be to collect, and then [reverse](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.reverse):

```
fn main() {
    let input = vec![2, 3, 4];
    let mut prod = 1;
    let mut p: Vec<usize> = input
        .iter()
        .rev()
        .map(|v| {
            prod *= v;
            prod
        }).collect();
    p.reverse();

    println!("{:?}", p);
}
```

Comment: Thanks much, @mcarton.
But to be exact, the expected result is `[24, 12, 4]`, so we need `rev` before `map`.

Comment: You don't. All you need is that you collect in reverse so a single `.rev()` *anywhere* before `.collect()` will do.

Answer (score 2):

Your `prod` variable is carrying state across from one item to the next, which is not what a mapping does. Mappings operate on each element independently, which makes them easily parallelized and easier to reason about. The result you're asking for is to be precise a [right scan](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:scanr1) (a reversed case of a [prefix sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum)), but I'm not sure there are convenient methods to collect from the right (probably the easiest mutable way would be using [`VecDeque::push_front`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.push_front)). This led me to perform the operation in two passes for my first version:

```
fn main() {
    let input: Vec<usize> = vec![2, 3, 4];
    let initprod = 1;
    let prev: Vec<usize> = input
        .iter()
        .rev()
        .scan(initprod, |prod, &v| {
            *prod *= v;
            Some(*prod)
        }).collect();
    let p: Vec<usize> = prev.into_iter().rev().collect();
    println!("{:?}", p);
}
```

Note that `initprod` is immutable; `prod` carries the state. Using `into_iter` also means `prev` is consumed. We could use `vec.reverse` as shown by mcarton, but then we need to have a mutable variable. Scans can be parallelized, but to a lesser degree than maps. See e.g. [discussion on adding them to Rayon](https://github.com/rayon-rs/rayon/issues/393). One might also consider if a [`ExactSizeIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html) should allow reverse collection into an ordinary vector, but the standard library [`scan`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.scan) method breaks the known size using `Option` (which by the `next` convention turns it into a take-while-scan).

Here's a fewer copy variant using a preallocated VecDeque to collect from the right. I used an extra scope to restrict the mutability. It also requires Rust 1.21 or later to use `for_each`. There's unnecessary overhead in tracking the number of items and ring buffer structure, but it's at least somewhat legible still.

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn main() {
    let input: Vec<usize> = vec![2,3,4];
    let p = {
        let mut pmut = VecDeque::with_capacity(input.len());
        let initprod = 1;
        input
            .iter()
            .rev()
            .scan(initprod, |prod, &v| {
                *prod *= v;
                Some(*prod)
            })
            .for_each(|v| { 
                pmut.push_front(v)
            });
        pmut
    };
    println!("{:?}", p);
}
```

Incidentally, following the old adage about Lisp programmers knowing the value of everything and the cost of nothing, here's a Haskell version I don't really know how inefficient it is:

```
scanr1 (*) [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: There's nothing *inherently* wrong with mutability in a language like Rust, which restricts mutable variables to only be used by one thing at a time. For example, I'd expect `Vec::reverse` to be way more efficient as it doesn't need to deallocate and reallocate space for the vector.

Comment: *collect from the right* — implementing `FromIterator` for a newtype over a `Vec` and doing `reverse` or a `VecDeque` and doing `push_front` seem plausible.

Comment: I agree, the reverse on a mutable vec is more efficient. It's merely a matter of confining the scope where mutation is appropriate to reduce the risk of following mistakes.

Comment: `let p = { /* ... */ pmut };` would be more idiomatic.