# Effect of `rev()` on iterator

Tags: rust

I am surprised by the effect of `.rev()` on an iterator pipeline.

If I do `iterator.map(do stuff).rev()`, I expect that

- first the map `do stuff` is done on the elements provided by the iterator
- then, the result is reversed (reverse iteration)

and if I do `iterator.rev().map(do stuff)`, I expect that:

- first the iteration is reversed (starting from the end)
- and then the map `do stuff` is done on the reversed iteration

However, I was surprised to find that this is not the case; these two codes give exactly the same result, and when `do stuff` has some side effect (like the example below), the result could be far from the expectations.

My questions:

- Is there any official documentation that explains that? (and why this behavior)
- If the results should be the same (I understand that reverse after map could imply extra storage), why do not ban the usage of `.rev()` after? (this should be possible with the type system).

Here an example: (This code sample converts minutes in minutes, hours, days, years)

```
fn f(mut minutes: u64) { // no .rev()
    let s = UNITS.iter().map(
        |count| process(&mut minutes, count)).collect::<Vec<String>>();
    println!("{:?}", s);
}

fn f_rev1(mut minutes: u64) { // .rev() before process
    let s = UNITS.iter().rev().map(
        |count| process(&mut minutes, count)).collect::<Vec<String>>();
    println!("{:?}", s);
}

fn f_rev2(mut minutes: u64) { // .rev() after process
    let s = UNITS.iter().map(
        |count| process(&mut minutes, count)).rev().collect::<Vec<String>>();
    println!("{:?}", s);
}

const UNITS: [u64; 4] = [60, 24, 365, 100];
fn main() {
    let minutes = 70;
    f(minutes);
    f_rev1(minutes);
    f_rev2(minutes);
}

fn process(minutes: &mut u64, count: &u64) -> String {
    let rem = *minutes % *count;
    *minutes /= *count;
    let r = format!("{}:{}", rem, count);
    println!("## {}", r);
    r
}
```

[Code in rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2fc2ef67b4b4d63c6a08084b55a7accc)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I cope with lazy iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765967/how-do-i-cope-with-lazy-iterators)

Comment: answer is iterator are lazy. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html#laziness

Comment: I am aware of the laziness of the iterators, but when the iterator is consumed why the `rev` *after* the process (which produces data) behaves as it was *before*?

Comment: because iterator are lazy.... rev position doesn't matter.

Comment: The only way to do the map to all elements in the original order and then yield them reversed would be to store the values somewhere. I guess you can get that with `iterator.map(stuff).collect::<Vec<_>>().into_iter().rev()` but then you are not being so lazy.

Comment: You cannot call `rev()` on every iterator, but only on those which also implement `DoubleEndedIterator`. Those are exactly the iterators that can be iterated lazily in reverse order.

Comment: If you want to reverse a vector use reverse https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2fc2ef67b4b4d63c6a08084b55a7accc

Comment: Thank you for the link to [Why does a doubly-reversed iterator act as if it was never reversed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52011912/why-does-a-doubly-reversed-iterator-act-as-if-it-was-never-reversed), it answers well to my question.

This is another example of the *best practices*, here, to avoid side effects. This was in a toy code, even in toys, it matters.